# Non-adjacent vertices have different colour?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

In a proper vertex coloured graph, can two non-adjacent vertices have different colours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can. In fact, if this is not allowed, then it may not even be possible to color some graphs, eg: a 5-cycle.